# What is the easiest way to classify recipients into seperate folders In Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 2013 (towards the company Office 365 server). I have a habit of classifying all my e-mail based on the topics and some (most?) of the people deal with a single topic (from my perspective). Thus I would like their e-mail to automatically land in a specific folder.

Ideally I would like to click on the recipient and mark something like "make all the e-mails from that person automatically go to into X folder".
Do you know of anything like that? An add-in? Or something?

Comment: Not sure if it's the same in 2013, but I think what you're looking for is called 'Rules and warnings' (roughly translated from my Dutch Outlook 2007)

Answer (score 0):

Select the message from required sender and click the "Rules" button on the ribbon. In the opened menu, select "Create Rule". Check "From sender@domain.com" (first one), "Move the item to folder:" (last one) and select the folder for this recipient. Click OK and OK. Now your rule is ready and will automatically move all messages from that sender to the specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rules, or buy third-party add-ons that will create folders (if needed) and move e-mail there based on the FROM address. This is really an outdated way of thinking though... You have a search e-mail for this purpose. There's really no point in filing all your e-mail in this way.